# how to send ArrayList of objects with intent

Tags: android, android-intent, arraylist

How i can send and receive ArrayList with intent? For example:

`ArrayList<model> m=new ArrayList<model>();`

the ArrayList contains string boolean and...

i tried this:

`intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(DATA,(ArrayList<? extends Parcelable>) m)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming an `ArrayList<Model>`:

For using `putParcelableArrayListEtra()` you need your `Model` class to implement the `Parcelable` interface. This involves quite a lot of boilerplate code, however, there is a [plugin for Android Studio](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7332-android-parcelable-code-generator) you can use to generate that code automatically.

Another option is, to make the `Model` class implement Serializable and use `putSerializable()`.

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

put arraylist in **Bundle** Like :

```
ArrayList<String> images=new ArrayList<>();    
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putSerializable("images", (Serializable) images);
```

and then put into intent extra.

Answer (score 1):

To send any object via `Intent` object should implements `Serializable` or `Parcelable`. Your `model` class should implement `Serializable` or `Parcelable`.

To send `ArrayList` via `Intent` all objects inside `ArrayList` should **implements** `Serializable` or `Parcelable`
Check [Parcelable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html) and [Serialization](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_serialization.htm) tutorial.